# Get all sessionScope variables in XPages

Tags: xpages

Lets say user A logs in and a sessionScope variable is set (This is just an example):

```
sessionScope.put("ABC", "ABC");
```

Now user B logs in and his sessionScope variable is set:

```
sessionScope.put("XYZ", "XYZ");
```

Is there a way where I can get all these sessionnScope variables/objects belonging to different users?

Answer (score 3):

In theory, you could register a sessionListener that stores in the applicationScope a pointer to each sessionScope that is created... but, in my opinion, that's a very bad idea. You'd have to be extremely careful to avoid exposing users' session data to each other.

Comment: How do you add a sessionListener without being able to modify web.xml?

Comment: Register it in the faces-config.xml. The XSP Starter Kit contains a reference implementation: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XSP%20Starter%20Kit

Comment: How to add this to the faces-config.xml? A < listener > - statement will be ignored?

Comment: Did you look at the reference implementation in the XSP Starter Kit?

Comment: I have looked in the XSP Starter Kit. But as far as I understand this seems to be more complicated. It is more then adding an entry to faces-config.xml. But thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

use the debugBar
http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPage%20Debug%20Toolbar

Comment: What you could do is using the debug bar as stated by Thomas. Another approach would be to log the set/get of the session scope vars in a file / database. But first things first.

Answer (score 1):

Session scopes belong to a single user so you cant retrieve them out of the box. You could add logging to the xpage/business log so you can keep track of the things that are going on. Another approach is to login as the user where you want to now the scopes from and use the debugbar to investigate

Answer (score 0):

SessionScope variables belong to a single instance of a browser/client. If you are Anonymous and log in as "user one" you have the same sessionScope as you did before. The same is true if you logout and log back in as "use two".

I have built an app which runs a method in the before page load of every page to assure the necessary sessionScope data is setup. One part of that data is the name of the user for whom the data is defined. That way, if the user name changes the we clear the data and reload it for the current user.

Using this approach you could define a MAP or JSON object with the username as the key which would keep the differences as people log in and out, but I am not sure that is a very sensible thing to do since changing identities is only realistic in development and testing. It is not a normal thing in production.

/Newbs